# Why DatagramSocketImpl joinGroup method takes a NetworkInterface if the socket must have already been bound to it?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

Just curious. Is that redundant? Haven't you already bound to the network you want to use? Perhaps that's for the case when you bound to 0.0.0.0 and now want to listen to multicast packets only from interface X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are bound to INADDR_ANY, which is the normal case, the join-group IGMP message goes out via whichever NIC interface the routing tables say gives the shortest route to the multicast address. In multi-homed hosts you may need it to go out via all NICs, so you loop over them joining via each in turn.
2. If you're bound to a specific NIC it doesn't make sense to specify a network interface when joining.
3. If you're bound to the multicast address itself, so that that socket can only receive multicasts, not unicast UDP, you may need to loop as in (1) if you want to join via all interfaces.

Comment: Can I say that the NetworkInterface address is only needed when I am not BOUND? I am curious to know what happens if I am bound to interface A and I call joinGroup with interface B. Any idea?

Comment: @chrisapotek (a) you are always 'bound', either to a specific NIC or to INADDR_ANY, as soon as you either bind(), connect(), send(), or receive(). (b) Possibly nothing will happen at all, but it depends on an arcane thing in TCP/IP called the 'weak end system model', which might mean you can receive multicasts via the 'wrong' interface anyway. I've been campaigning against what I described in your original post as the Linux aberration, but on re-reading W.R. Stevens it now seems to me that binding to the m/c group address is possibly the best option of all, if your system supports it.