# Does INADDR_ANY care about new interface?

Tags: sockets, interface, network-programming, bind, in-addr

From reading from other posts

[understanding INADDR_ANY for socket programming - c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508685/understanding-inaddr-any-for-socket-programming-c)

> INADDR_ANY is used when you don't need to bind a socket to a specific
>   IP. When you use this value as the address when calling bind(), the
>   socket accepts connections to all the IPs of the machine

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange

> by default we bind transports to INADDRANY/0.0.0.0, so when sending
>   outgoing (UDP) packets, we rely on the OS to select the correct
>   interface for us, based on what interfaces are currently online and
>   the OS's internal routing table. In other words, we just call sendto()
>   and let the OS "do the right thing". In case of IP address change, we
>   are also relying on the OS to switch the interface from one interface
>   to the new one for our UDP transmissions

Supposed that previously I have 2 interface A, B when binding my socket using `IADDR_ANY`. After that I have interface C available (This is the case on mobile device, when user turns on 3G, Wifi)

1. Will this socket accept connections from C
2. If I turn off A, B, will this socket use C to send packets ?

**P/S**: Answers targeting iOS and Android (both SDK and NDK socket) are more appreciated