# gcc struct assignment warning missing braces around initializer

Tags: c, gcc, struct, gcc-warning

[struct rtentry](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/route.h)

The following

```
#include <net/route.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
int main(){
  struct rtentry e={};
  *((struct sockaddr_in*)(&(e.rt_genmask)))=(struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family=AF_INET,.sin_port=0,.sin_addr=INADDR_ANY};
  return 0;
}
```

gives the warning (gcc -std=c11 -Wall test.c)

```
test.c:5:45: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
    5 |   *((struct sockaddr_in*)(&(e.rt_genmask)))=(struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family=AF_INET,.sin_port=0,.sin_addr=INADDR_ANY};
      |                                             ^
                                         ^
```

Why? How may I fix the code?

Comment: `rtenty` or `rtentry`? I found latter in route.h.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It copmiles if I use C compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/xKETe3 . But if I switch to C++ compiler, there is error not warning.

Comment: @LouisGo `-Wall`

Comment: `.sin_addr={INADDR_ANY}` - sin_addr is a composite. This will also make it c++ friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [INADDR_ANY is macro defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510000/4123703).
2. `in_addr` is a struct for wrapping value.
   You need to use `.sin_addr={INADDR_ANY}` to make sure it's initialized by value `INADDR_ANY`.

```
           struct sockaddr_in {
               sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
               in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
               struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
           };

           /* Internet address. */
           struct in_addr {
               uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
           };
```

Fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/xM8r1E

```
#include <net/route.h>

int main(void) {
    struct rtentry e={};
    *(struct sockaddr_in*)(&(e.rt_dst))=(struct sockaddr_in){
    .sin_family=AF_INET,
    .sin_port=0,
    .sin_addr={INADDR_ANY}
    };
    return 0;
}
```