# MulticastSocket constructors and binding to port or SocketAddress

Tags: java, multicast, multicastsocket

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of the term binding here but I am confused about the usage of the [MulticastSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) and it's constructors. They no not do what *I* understand they should do *should* do so any who can help me clear my misunderstanding would be appreciated.

Firstly what I am trying to achieve. I have tried to write a short program that creates a MulticastSocket bind it (i.e. listen) on a ***specific network adapter*** and then join a specific Multicast group. I have tried the following (client) code which works ok, I can multicast a packet to it without the Multicast socket timing out.

```
public class Main {
public static final int DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT = 5555;
public static final String multicastGroup = "225.4.5.6";
public static final String adapterName = "eth0";
public static final int MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 65507;

CharBuffer charBuffer = null;
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
static ByteBuffer message = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
static boolean loop = true;

static byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        //MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.2.23", DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));
        MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT);
        mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName);
        mSocket.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress(multicastGroup, DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT),NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName));
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
        while (loop){
            try{
                mSocket.receive(p);
                System.out.println("Packet Received.");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){
                System.out.println("Socket Timed out");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

}
```

}

Unfortunately as soon as I alter the MulticastSocket constructor to `MulticastSocket(SocketAddress bindaddr)` it stops working. It seems I can only use the bind-to-port constructor for it to work so what does it exactly bind to when this constructor is called as I have not specified a network adapter at this stage. (I know I join the group with a specific NetworkInterface later on, but how can I be sure that during the constructor call it doesn't bind to ANY adapter?)

I could also join a group without specifying the adapter then I don't know which adapter it's bound to.

Can anyone explain what binding to a port *only* actually does and is it possible to listen only on a specific NetworkInterface?

Updated #1 **

Having read the replies so far and discussed this with a work colleague, the following is my understanding of Java MulticastSocket:

1. MulticastSocket() creates a multicast socket bound a port selected at random (by the host's underlying OS bound to the wildcard address 0.0.0.0 i.e. ALL network cards. However calling this constructor with *null* creates an unbound MulticastSocket. In this scenario calling the `bind(SocketAddress) method binds to a IP and port.
2. MulticastSocket(int port) creates a multicast socket bound to a specific port but on EVERY IP address.
3. MulticastSocket(SocketAddress sa) creates a multicast socket bound to the specified IP address (which could be ANY IP address, *even* an invalid Multicast address) and port.

Using option 2, this means *potentially* any packet sent to the specified port, regardless of its actual destination will be passed to the MulticastSocket. I say potentially because Multicast packets will only arrive if the group has been joined (but other packets destined to non-Multicast addresses will arrive *provided the port number matches*?)

Using option 3, I can bind to an IP address and *only* packets whose destination matches will arrive at the socket. It would be perfectly feasible with this option to bind to the IP of a particular network interface however no Multicast packets would be received because they would not be destined for the specific IP address of the network card (which is why I never saw them arrive on the code example). It is possible to also bind to a valid Multicast address but in this scenario *only* specific packets whose destination matches the bound multicast address would arrive at the socket, *regardless of calls to `joinGroup()`*.

Now the calls to `joinGroup()` do *nothing* to the socket itself but issue an IGMP request to the underlying network system to ensure that routers, the OS itself etc actually start *routing* the specified multicast packets up the hardware and through the network stack and finally to the Java MulticastSocket itself.

** **Update 2** **
Quoting from "UNIX Network Programming", Stevens, Fenner, Rudoff:

> To receive a multicast datagram, a process must join the multicast
>   group and it must also *bind* a UDP socket to the prot number that
>   will be used as destination port number for datagrams sent to the
>   group. The two operations are distinct and both are required. Joining
>   the group tells the host's IP layer and datalink layer to receive
>   multicast datagrams sent to that group. Binding the port is how the
>   application specifies to UDP that it wants to receive datagrams sent
>   to that port. Some applications also bind the multicast address to the
>   socket, in addition to the port. this prevents any other datagrams
>   that might be received for that port to other unicast, broadcast or
>   multicast addresses from being delivered to the socket.

I think that explains it all.

** **Update 3** **
Just wanted to post the code I tested and the comments explains what happens with each.

```
/**
         * This first creates an UNBOUND Multicast Socket and then binds to
         * a port (but accepting the wildcard IP 0.0.0.0.
         * The Following WORKS:
         */

        /*MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(null);
        mSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));
        mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName);
        mSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(multicastGroup));
        */

        /**
         * The following creates a a network socket and binds in the constructor
         * to a local adapter and port. Consequently it DOES not work because
         * it only allows destination ips that match the bound address & port
         * even though the desired group is joined.
         */

        /*MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.2.23", DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));
        mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName);
        mSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(multicastGroup));*/


        /**
         * The following binds to the same multicast group this is 'joined' later
         * and this works correctly. However if the join() is NOT called, no packets 
         * arrive at the socket, as expected.
         */

        /*MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress(multicastGroup, DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));

        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName);
        // Comment out the following line and it no longer workds correctly.
        mSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(multicastGroup));*/

        /**
         * The following binds to a a specified port on 0.0.0.0 and joins 
         * a specific Multicast group on a specific adapter. This must mean that the IGMP must occur 
         * on the specified adapter.
         * 
         * ** This will ALSO receive packets addressed DIRECTLY to the ip 192.168.2.23 with the same
         * port as DEFAULT_MULTICAST_POR ***ONLY!!***
         */
        MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT);
        mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.23"));
        mSocket.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress(multicastGroup, DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT),NetworkInterface.getByName(adapterName));

        /**
         * The following binds to a specific address and port (i.e. adapter address)
         * and then ONLY accepts UDP packets with destination equal to that IP.
         */
        /*MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.2.23", DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));
        mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.23"));*/
```

Comment: Creating a Multicast Socket  with SocketAddress means we are binding the socket to the SocketAddress right? So If we join to a Multicast group, why the socket unable to receive multicast datagrams????

Comment: Well here's a sentence that makes absolutely zero sense: `This will ALSO receive packets addressed DIRECTLY to the ip 192.168.2.23 with the same port as DEFAULT_MULTICAST_POR ***ONLY!!***`...how can it be ALSO and ONLY simultaneously. That's logically impossible, so I have no idea what you're talking about and I'd like to know because I would also like to learn more about this.

Comment: @searchengine27perhaps if you were more polite in your response I'd be inclined to assist.

Comment: That makes zero sense. You're literally looking to pick a fight over a comment that is literally just stating facts? There was nothing polite or impolite about it - it's just a fact. Now you're being impolite :) Thanks for proving that you're not capable of being a respected member of the community :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a local IP address when you create or bind it, it binds to 0.0.0.0, which means 'accept input via any NIC'. This is normally what you want.

It is possible to bind to a specific IP address, which implicitly means the corresponding NIC, but some systems such as Linux seem to expect multicast sockets, if bound, to be bound to the multicast group itself. This doesn't make any sense to me: what if you want to join another group?

I think the best and most portable idea is to listen at 0.0.0.0 and join via either a specific NIC, or via *all* NICs, one at a time. The latter is necessary in multi-homed hosts unless you are confident that the default route to the multicast group is the one you want the join request sent out on, because that's what happens if you don't specify a join interface.

Comment: After further contemplation, I've added further info to the question and would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: If you use your option 3 you should also join via that interface, as I said above. It's still liable to the problem of receiving non-multicasts though. You could try binding to the multicast address itself, but it may not work on your platform, as I also said above.

Comment: EJP I think we basically agree on what happens, but I should point out that in the tets I've done it's possible to bind a Multicast socket to a NON Multicast address and this essentially prevents any Multicast packet being received. I realise now that `join()` and bind()` are two different things. It is also possible to use this MulticastSocket bound to a NON-Multicast address to receive datagrams destined to that NON-Multicast address. That makes sense as MulticaseSocket is just a specialisation of DatagramSocket. I use Linux which allowed binding. I care not for Windows.

Comment: I will post a summary of my tests soon for future reference if anyone else ponders this deeply on it...

Comment: "it binds to 0.0.0.0, which means 'accept input via any NIC'" - this is not true

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692956/what-does-it-mean-to-bind-a-multicast-udp-socket/10739443#10739443

Comment: @haelix Your answer there agrees with me: "This explains why when binding to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) I received datagrams sent to my multicast group".

Comment: @Kerry If you bind to a specific non-multicast address that isn't the static IP route to where the multicasts are coming from, you have to join the group via the NIC that *is* the static route, or, for simplicity, via all of them, as I said above. I don't see any evidence anywhere that you've done that. I have, in a working product, and my patch to that effect was accepted into Jini many years ago.

Comment: @EJP "when binding to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) I received datagrams sent to my multicast group" -- yes I did, but not because 0.0.0.0 means "accept input via any nic". Did you try binding to the NIC? Doesn't work. As my answer explains, and as I've seen things work (or not), INADDR_ANY is a wildcard for the multicast address, not for NIC to bind to.

Comment: @haelix You are mistaken. 0.0.0.0 means INADDR_ANY means 'any NIC', and your own experience proves it. It is also used when binding listening sockets in TCP,  which has nothing to do with multicast. I suggest you do some reading. My book is still available from Springer.

Comment: You are right about TCP: the address specified during binding is a local interface or "ANY". But for multicast, if I bind to the network interface over which traffic is received, I get no packets. This implies that the meaning of the bind address is *not* a local interface address, and consequently, INADDR_ANY does *not* mean 'any NIC'. This is the conclusion drawn from my experience: that the address specified during bind has a *filtering* role: binding to INADDR_ANY means no filtering, and binding to the actual muticast group means to filter out packets coming from other addresses.

Comment: (This is consistent with *Update #2* in the OP's question.)

Comment: @haelix Your experience is consistent with my answer, and you have zero evidence that your answer is more correct. I suggest you try it. Bind a MulticastSocket as you describe, then send yourself a datagram to that port via the real IP address of the host. If you don't, you are correct. If you do, you're wrong. Looking forward to the result.

Comment: @EJP sorry, my experience is consistent with my answer not yours. I already did the experiments, and am basing my answers on that. I have no interest to repeat, as I found evidence in literature that my point of view is correct - The Sockets Networking API by W.R Stevens -- as quoted in my linked Q&A above.

Comment: @haelix We are still waiting for your evidence. You are asserting a condition that appears in no documentation and that you haven't verified experimentally and you expect other people to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the point with your address binding:

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html
A multicast group is specified by a class D IP address and by a standard UDP port number. Class D IP addresses are in the range 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255, inclusive. The address 224.0.0.0 is reserved and should not be used.

Comment: Missing the point now exactly? His multicast address looks OK to me at first glance.

Comment: @EJP I am talking about the commented out code that does NOT work as I understood it `//MulticastSocket mSocket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.2.23", DEFAULT_MULTICAST_PORT));`

Comment: Germann, thanks for your reply. would you be able to comment on the additiona linfo I added?

Comment: I did not check if traffic actually goes to ALL addresses - could be interesting, unfortunately I don't have enough computers at the moment to check myself. If you can set it up and report on your findings.

Comment: AFAIR Multicast is basically the same as broadcast (i.e. the packets will be sent to ALL available addresses), the difference is that you have to subscribe (join) to receive multicast. Where and how did you find that joinGroup() actually affects the network and not the receiver? I would expect option 3 - MulticastSocket binding to invalid address to fail either immediately or at least as soon as you attempt to start using it.

Comment: Germann, I have tried using MulticastSocket in the ways I detailed in the additional info above (apart from frem seeing if 'normal' IP destinations get through if bound to a 'normal' IP) and so far it seems to work as I described above. Also quoting from the book "Unix Network Programming, Stevens, Fenner, Rudoff", "When a process on a host joins a multicast group, that host sends an IGMP message to any attached multicast routers ..". Multicast is more than just filtering at the application level it requires hardware outside of the host to cooperate also.

Comment: I repeat. What point has he missed in the code that is commented out? You haven't answered that. And your remarks about multicast are quite incorrect. Kerry clearly knows a lot more about it than you do. A join request engages in the IGMP protocol to tell the nearest router there is a member on this side, so it knows to forward multicasts to that group: otherwise it doesn't. That's why multicast is different from broadcast. You seem to be just guessing.

Comment: Germann, the thing I didn't realise is that `binding` and `joining` are two different things entirely. You can bind to ANY IP address, but you can only join a Multicast IP address.