# Join multicast group using DatagramChannel without specifying network interface

Tags: java, networking, multicast, datagram

When using java's multicast socket I can join a multicast group without specifying a `NetworkInterface` using this code:

```
MulticastSocket sock = new MulticastSocket(PORT);
sock.joinGroup(ADDR);
```

If I want to use NIO on the other hand I can do:

```
DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
        .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
        .bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT))
        .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, IFC);

dc.join(ADDR, IFC);
```

where `IFC` is the `NetworkInterface` I am interested on. 
If I dont know the network interface in advance how can I join a group like with the `MulticastSocket?`

One solution that I found is using this code:

```
MulticastSocket msock = new MulticastSocket();
NetworkInterface ifc = msock.getNetworkInterface();
msock.close();
DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
        .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
        .bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT))
        .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ifc);

dc.join(ADDR, ifc);
```

Surprisingly this code works and performed as expected, when looking on the NetworkInterface returned by the `MulticastSocket.getNetworkInterface()` method I saw that it returned an interface named "0.0.0.0" which of course does not exists. Moreover there is no way to get this network interface  with any of the `NetworkInterface.*` factories

Is the solution reliable? can anyone explain why it works and if there is a better way to achieve what I wants?

Comment: Hava a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392173/multicastsocket-constructors-and-binding-to-port-or-socketaddress

Comment: Well evidently `MulticastSocket.getNetworkInterface()` returns a magical `0.0.0.0 NetworkInterface` you can't get any other way. It wouldn't do that if you had called `MulticastSocket.setNetworkInterface()`. It's curious that the NIO version doesn't have a one-argument `join()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I using local address can find LAN devices! so you can try it!
e.g 

`NetworkInterface IFC = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());`