# IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP on a socket, will the socket listen to unicast also?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multicast, setsockopt

Considering the code below,

I'm trying to bind a UDP socket for multicast.
I've bound it to a specific port, and set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` for the address to listen to.

My question: will the socket receive unicast UDP packets bound for that port? If so, how can I prevent it? I wish to only receive multicast.

```
int fd;
if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

u_int yes = 1;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0)
{
    perror("Reusing ADDR failed");
    exit(1);
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = (source_iface.empty()
                          ? htonl(INADDR_ANY)
                          : inet_addr(source_iface.c_str()));

if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

struct ip_mreq mreq;
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(group.c_str());
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = (source_iface.empty()
                               ? htonl(INADDR_ANY)
                               : inet_addr(source_iface.c_str()));

if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
{
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at the incoming packet's destination IP address (as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet ) and ignore the packet if that IP address is not a multicast IP address?  (OTOH you might want to review *why* you don't want to receive unicast packets -- presumably they are being sent to you for a good reason)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll also need to `bind` on the particular multicast address on which you want to listen, and not just in the `setsockopt` call - the latter also being necessary to make sure that the network card and IGMP also do the right thing.

See also [What does it mean to bind a multicast (UDP) socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10692956/6782)

Comment: In the code, I see a `bind()` call although `INADDR_ANY` is probably wrong in this context...

Comment: @AlexisWilke Well as INADDR_ANY isn't a multicast address, of course it is wrong in this context, if the solution provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got my instance to work so I know what the problem was. The `bind()` has to occur against the multicast IP address:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = (group.empty()
                          ? htonl(INADDR_ANY)   // <-- this will work here but not below
                          : inet_addr(group.c_str()));

if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}
```

The difference here is `group` instead of `source_iface`. Until I changed that, it would not receive broadcasted packets at all.