# Multicast not being sent to all Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, multicast, docker-network

I have 3 services defined in docker-compose. One of them sends a multicast that should be received by the other 2 services, but only one of them receives it. The 2 receivers are in different networks, and the sender is part of both networks.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  sender:
    networks:
      - network_a
      - network_b

  receiver1:
    networks:
      - network_a
    depends_on:
      - sender

  receiver2:
    networks:
      - network_b
    depends_on:
      - sender

networks:
  network_a:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
        gateway: 172.20.1.1

  network_b:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.20.2.0/24
        gateway: 172.20.2.1
```

**receiver1 gets the multicast but receiver2 doesn't.**

If I remove network_a from sender networks field, then receiver2 receives the message. Somehow multicast doesn't work on multiple networks.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23659 Quoted from there: "If you do not bind a local interface address to the multicast sender socket, Linux (afaik) will select your default routes interface address."

Comment: @CFrei Thank you, you were right, that was the path to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself as I found out what was the problem.

The problem isn't with Docker or anything related to Docker, it's strictly a **multicast** issue.

Basically, multicast works only in one network and **if you want to send a multicast message in multiple networks you have to iterate through all the networks interfaces** to be used.

For example, in Java, you would have to call *setInterface()* method before sending the multicast message to specify exactly the used network.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html#setInterface(java.net.InetAddress)

Comment: Also, this helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29526884/3283292

Comment: My use case is simpler than yours. I've only one network. Do you've any update this issue?